# Can this be handled using only Sharepoint 2007 designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We have an upcoming project a client wants us to work on but we're only allowed to use sharepoint 2007 designer.  No custom webparts.
Basically, our client has a bunch of photos he wants to allow users to download but only if they submit a request for the photo & he reviews their info.  If he approves their request, he'll send the photo. I'm not very experienced in sharepoint, so can the following be done using only sp designer to handle this?  If not, do you see any workaround of tweak we can do to this process:

1) Create 2 document libraries.  One for the low-res copies of the photos.  One for high-res copies.

2) The library with low-res photos will be available to all users.  Everyone can see them.  The high-res photo library however will be restricted to only "approved" users.

3) If a user sees a photo they like, a "Download" button will be available to them for this photo.

4) Clicking the Download button will open a custom form where they enter some basic info about them self and then submit it.

5) Our client can then go in and review each submitted form request where he'll have the ability to "Approve" the request.

6) If he clicks "Approve", 2 things happen.  One, an email will be sent to the user, containing the url to the high res image.  And two, that user will receive permissions to download that high-res image (but still won't have permissions to download other high-res images).

Can all of this be done using only sharepoint designer 2007?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-workflow-HA010100591.aspx) to automate the process. But I don't know does SharePoint 2007 provide needed activities for you purpose.